# C# Programmatically Disable Large Send Offload (LSO)

Tags: c#, .net

We deploy an application that requires several specific NIC related configuration changes.  One of these changes is disabling "Large Send Offload V2" or "LSO" from all NIC's.  Is there a way to do this programmatically with C# and .NET?  I would like to write a simple Console or Forms based application that can do this automatically.  I have been exploring System.Management.ManagementClass, but it does not seem to have these advanced options.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

[image]

Comment: You could perhaps research to see if those settings are in fact in the registry - and if so, you could do it that way.

Comment: I haven't been able to find it in the registry, but I will keep looking.

Comment: Maybe using NetworkInterface class and .GetProperties()?

Comment: Can you send me the reference for that class?  I'm only finding Win32_NetworkAdapter, and I do not believe it has a GetProperties method.

Comment: Perhaps this document: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/network/using-registry-values-to-enable-and-disable-task-offloading) - Take a look at the bottom and there's the registry location.

Comment: @AtomicFireball, I am familiar with that page.  Unfortunately, those are global settings, not adapter specific.

Comment: @GED125 There are powershell cmdlets that can do it with `Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty`. I'm not sure which API this uses to make the changes though.  `Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty Ethernet -DisplayName "Large Send Offload V2 (IPv4)" -DisplayValue "Disabled" -NoRestart`

Comment: @AtomicFireball, thank you!  I will look into this.

Comment: @AtomicFireball, your method worked!  Would you like to write it up so I can give you credit?

Comment: @GED125 done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a C# way, but there are PowerShell cmdlets that can do it with Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty. I'm not certain which API this uses to make the changes though.

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty Ethernet -DisplayName "Large Send Offload V2 (IPv4)" -DisplayValue "Disabled" -NoRestart
```

Comment: I _think_ c# has support for command line processes via `Process.Invoke` or something similar

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble it does. You can also use System.Management.Automation to invoke PowerShell directly from C# and get objects. [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)